# Tengo esta matriz generada con as.data.frame.matrix() y necesito reordenar el índice segun el orden de los días, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Tags: r

```
p2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(Dia = p$Dia, Mes = p$Mes))
p2 <- p2 %>% select("enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre")

p2 

          enero febrero marzo abril mayo junio julio agosto septiembre octubre
viernes     108      63    42    24   29    67    44     86         69      45
lunes        41      31    47    62   47    32    66     25         42      60
martes       24      34    63    23   32    54    32     77         62      56
miércoles   102      43    65    49   43    48    35     81         25      37
jueves       46      85    64    45   82    52    40     83         50     101
sábado        0       4     0     0    9     0     0     25          1       5
          noviembre diciembre
viernes          33        45
lunes            69        64
martes           35        39
miércoles        57        59
jueves           68        84
sábado            1         0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estas hablando de los `rowname`, para reordenar las filas según el orden cronológico de la semana, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
semana <- c('lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo')
df[match(semana, rownames(df), nomatch=0), ]
```

- Definimos un vector con cada nombre de día en el orden deseado
- Con `match(semana, rownames(df), nomatch=0)` generamos un vector de índices que corresponden a la posición que debería ocupar cada fila según el orden de `semana`